# Why did the panorama option disappear?

Tags: photos, samsung-galaxy-s-5

When I got my phone, I could take panorama pictures.

Then the option disappeared. What gives?

If I remember correctly, there was simply an option on this tool tray:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(click screenshot for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my S4 with Verizon's version of Lollipop, this option isn't in the settings menus; it's one of the entries under the "Mode" button on the actual viewfinder screen.

Comment: indeed! can't believe i missed it right under my nose! thanks.